# Question about "short" in this sentence

Tags: short-selling

I was reading an article by David Stockman from (http://davidstockmanscontracorner.com/take-cover-now-they-dont-ring-a-bell-at-the-top/). He uses the word "short" in a way I'm unfamiliar with. If you read the paragraph below, he says "there are no shorts left." What does that mean? I understood it that when you short the market you're betting that it's going to go down. What does it mean here?

> But that is the Achilles heel of the game. As the bubble takes on ever
>   greater girth, it becomes increasingly susceptible to a negative shock
>   to confidence. Part of the reason is technical.  When markets reach
>   their current nose bleed levels there are no shorts left; and it is
>   also likely that the day trading gamblers have become increasingly lax
>   about absorbing the cost of even cheap “downside insurance” (i.e. puts
>   on the S&P 500). That is, they are “long” and “unprotected”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He refers to investors with a negative outlook who have short positions.